# Is it possible to detect selecting element from datalist?

Tags: angularjs, html-datalist

I would like to have effectively two kinds of events -- the entry has changed, and user selected something from the given list. I tried to add `ng-click` event to the options but it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
<input id="product" type="text" list="products" ng-model="product"
       autocomplete="off" ng-change="productChanged()">
  <datalist id="products">
    <option ng-repeat="elem in products" class="list-group-item"
            value="{{$index}}"
            ng-click="productSelected()">{{elem.name}}</option>
  </datalist>
```

Because I cannot find solution I am considering the **UGLY** hack (I don't have numbers on the list) -- I set value to index, so if I get in `productChanged` a number, this was made by selecting the entry. If not -- it was typed in.

But as I said, it is ugly. Is there a righteous way to do it?

Comment: If user selects, doesn't that automatically trigger ng-change? Why would you need two different events if both are caused by the same action?

Comment: @DavidH., because it is text input with preset autocomplete really, so user can type in arbitrary text. And I would like to know if user selected something from the list or typed in something completely new.

Comment: Are you searching for something like this: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##typeaheads ?

Comment: @developer033, looks nice! Thank you. If I am not mistaken it has appropriate event `onSelect`. I will try for now without external libs though, because the page is simple and I am afraid of loading lib per each problem I encounter.

Comment: Yes, it's a perfect autocomplete and so simple to manage.